# replace part of string with values from dictionary?

Tags: python-polars

Loving the Polars library for its fantastic speed and easy syntax!

Struggling with this question - is there an analogue in Polars for the Pandas code below? Would like to replace strings using a dictionary.

Tried using this expression, but it returns 'TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable'

```
pl.col("List").str.replace_all(lambda key: key,dict())
```

Trying to replace the Working Pandas code below with a Polars expression

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'List':[
    'Systems',
    'Software',
    'Cleared'
    ]})

dic = {
    'Systems':'Sys'
    ,'Software':'Soft'
    ,'Cleared':'Clr'
    }

df["List"] = df["List"].replace(dic, regex=True)
```

Output:

```
 List
 0   Sys
 1  Soft
 2   Clr
```

Comment: I would think you're better off turning your lookup dict into another dataframe and then joining them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could build an expression by chaining multiple `.replace_all()` calls.

```
>>> replacements = pl.col("List")
>>> for old, new in dic.items():
...    replacements = replacements.str.replace_all(old, new)
>>> df.select(replacements)
shape: (3, 1)
┌──────┐
│ List │
│ ---  │
│ str  │
╞══════╡
│ Sys  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Soft │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Clr  │
└──────┘
```

You can pass `literal=True` to `.replace_all()` if you don't need/want regex matching.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet would be to turn your dic into a dataframe and join the two.

You need to convert your dic to the format which will make a nice DataFrame.  You can do that as a list of dicts so that you have

```
dicdf=pl.DataFrame([{'List':x, 'newList':y} for x,y in dic.items()])
```

where `List` is what your column name is and we're arbitrary making `newList` our new column name that we'll get rid of later

You'll want to join that with your original df and then select all columns except the old `List` plus `newList` but renamed to `List`

```
df=df.join(
    dicdf, 
    on='List') \
.select([
    pl.exclude(['List','newList']), 
    pl.col('newList').alias('List')
 ])
```

Comment: Definitely an option, thanks