# Python Polars - how to replace strings in a df column with lists with values from dictionary?

Tags: python, python-polars

This is a follow up to a [question that previously answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74738149/replace-part-of-string-with-values-from-dictionary).

Have a large dataframe df that looks like this (list in column 'SKU')

```
| SKU                                                                  | Count | Percent     
|----------------------------------------------------------------------|-------|-------------|
| "('000000009100000749',)"                                            | 110   | 0.029633621 |
| "('000000009100000749', '000000009100000776')"                       | 1     | 0.000269397 |
| "('000000009100000749', '000000009100000776', '000000009100002260')" | 1     | 0.000269397 |
| "('000000009100000749', '000000009100000777', '000000009100002260')" | 1     | 0.000269397 |
| "('000000009100000749', '000000009100000777', '000000009100002530')" | 1     | 0.000269397 |
```

Need to replace the values in the 'SKU' column with corresponding values from a dictionary df_unique that looks like this (please ignore format below, it is a dict):

| skus str | code i64 |
| --- | --- |
| 000000009100000749 | 1 |
| 000000009100000785 | 2 |
| 000000009100002088 | 3 |

I have tried this code:

```
replacements = pl.col("SKU")

for old, new in df_unique.items():
    replacements = replacements.str.replace_all(old, new)
df = df.select(replacements)
```

*Get this error:
SchemaError: Series of dtype: List(Utf8) != Utf8*

I have tried to change the column values to string, alhtough I think it is redundant, but same error

```
df= df.with_column(
    pl.col('SKU').apply(lambda row: [str(x) for x in row])
    )
```

Any guidance on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would help if you showed the actual list type of the column:

It looks like you have *"stringified"* tuples but it's not entirely clear.

```
df = pl.DataFrame({
   "SKU": [["000000009100000749"], ["000000009100000749", "000000009100000776"]]
})
sku_to_code = {
    "000000009100000749": 1,
    "000000009100000785": 2,
    "000000009100002088": 3
}
```

```
>>> df
shape: (2, 1)
┌─────────────────────────────────────┐
│ SKU                                 │
│ ---                                 │
│ list[str]                           │
╞═════════════════════════════════════╡
│ ["000000009100000749"]              │
├─────────────────────────────────────┤
│ ["000000009100000749", "00000000... │
└─────────────────────────────────────┘
```

When dealing with list columns - [`.arr.eval()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.arr.eval.html#polars.Expr.arr.eval) can be used to run expressions against each element in the list.

[`pl.element()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.element.html#polars-element) is used to refer to each individual element:

```
replace_sku = pl.element()
for old, new in df_unique.items():
    replace_sku = replace_sku.str.replace_all(old, str(new), literal=True)
```

```
>>> df.select(pl.col("SKU").arr.eval(replace_sku, parallel=True))
shape: (2, 1)
┌─────────────────────────────┐
│ SKU                         │
│ ---                         │
│ list[str]                   │
╞═════════════════════════════╡
│ ["1"]                       │
├─────────────────────────────┤
│ ["1", "000000009100000776"] │
└─────────────────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

Column `SKU` has `list[str]` dtype, but next you calling attribute `.str` (here: `replacements.str.replace_all(old, new)`) which is for string. You should use attribute `.arr` with columns that have `list` dtype and [corresponding methods](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/array.html).

You can use sol-n below with `.apply()` or use sol-n by [jqurious](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75049440/13469933) which works **much faster** (because `.arr.eval()` allows to run all expression parallel)

```py
d = {"000000009100000749": 1, "000000009100000776": 2}
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "SKU": [["000000009100000749", "000000009100000776"]]
})
    

df = df.with_column(
    col("SKU").apply(
        lambda row: [d[i] for i in row]
    ).alias("SKU_replaced")
)
```

Comment: Thanks. This would work but I am stuck with the original col("SKU") in format list[str]. I am sure it is something trivial but unable to convert to string dtype. Last hurdle and help appreciated in advance.

Comment: Okay, I fixed code. You have error cause you call `.str` attribute instead of `.arr` (because your column has `list` type)

Comment: Thank you both! Took me a while to realize that df_unique is actually a list of dictionaries, instead of a dictionary. Needed slight tweak and I have added to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Both solutions from [jqurious](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75049440/20256664) and [glebcom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75043662/20256664) above work perfectly for the asked question.

I had not realized that df_unique is a list of dictionaries and not a dict and had to tweak the solution according. Here is the slightly modified solution from jqurious looks like (change the loop to iterate over the elements in the df_unique list of dicts):

```
replace_sku = pl.element()
for item in df_unique:
    old = item['SKU']
    new = item['code']
    replace_sku = replace_sku.str.replace_all(old, str(new), literal=True)

df = df.select(pl.col("SKU").arr.eval(replace_sku, parallel=True))
```

Comment: If `df_unique` has many rows, it is possible to overflow the stack though due to too large of an expression tree.